# Query Domain on New Tab Page Load via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, console.log

Whenever a tab is active and the domain/page has fully loaded, I'd like to simply log the domain (or full web address) to the console once my chrome extension is clicked on by a user. In its current state, this works except only on a tab where a web page was loaded previously. If I click to create a new tab and then navigate to a domain, nothing happens and i have to switch to another tab and then back again to log the information.

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
"scripts": [
  "background.js",
  "popup.js"
],
"persistent": false
},
...
"permissions": ["tabs"]
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  console.log("The extension has been installed successfully.");
});
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
    },
  function (tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    var url = tab.url;
    var host = tab.hostname;
    console.log("id: " + tab.id + "url:" + tab.url + "domain:" + tab.hostname + "description: " + title);
    });
});
```

Comment: Make sure to study the architecture article in the documentation - it looks like you're confusing a browserAction script with a background script. Remove popup.js altogether, put its code in background.js, and use chrome.browserAction.onClicked listener instead of onActivated+query, for which you'll need ”browser_action”:{} in manifest.json, just make sure to check the documentation for the exact syntax and parameters.